# How to Handle SQL connection reference in Power Apps ALM using Azure Devops CICD?

Tags: azure-devops, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have developed a power app which has Azure SQL Database as the Data Source. I want to move this app to higher Environment using Azure Devops. I am able to successfully import the App using Azure Devops but I am unable to handle the SQL Connector which differs from Environment to Environment.

***Note: I am using SQL Authentication with ADMIN Account details?***

I want to know how can I handle this connection issue in Azure Devops?

Comment: @SebastianZolg - can you please Help me

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Yes we need to use deployment Setting file to deploy. Please refer below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/conn-ref-env-variables-build-tools